# How to consume Web API in an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web application to update data?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I have existing Web API to consume in an ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC web application.

Both API and web app should be communicating within the same domain server but with different port number.

I already add update operations in order to update the data records in database. In the view page, display all data and all data shall can be updated once I click on 'Save and Update' button.

But when I try to update and click on the 'Save and Update' button, it doesn't work. The data cannot be update to database.

What I've tried so far:

I configured HTTP client in `Program.cs` in the MVC web app:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("API", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://ipServerAddress:8088"); // API server URL
    // Add any additional configurations if required (e.g., default headers, timeout, etc.)
});
```

I created a service to consume the API. The service class will use the configured `HttpClient` to make the requests to the API endpoints:

```
namespace Test.Services
{
    public class APIService
    {
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

        public APIService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        }

        public async Task<TimeInUser> GetTimeInUserByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("API");

            var response = await client.GetAsync($"/api/Users/GetUsers/{id}");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var timeInUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TimeInUser>(content);
                return timeInUser;
            }

            return null;
        }

        public async Task<TimeInUser> UpdateTimeInUserAsync(TimeInUser updatedUser)
        {
            var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("API");

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(updatedUser);
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var response = await client.PutAsync($"/api/Users/UpdateTimeInUser/{updatedUser.Id}", content);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var updatedContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TimeInUser>(updatedContent);
                return result;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I inject the service into the MVC controller to use it to consume the API:

```
public class RegistrationController : Controller
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;
    private readonly APIService _apiService;

    public RegistrationController(DbContext context, APIService apiService)
    {
        _context = context;
        _apiService = apiService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateUserDetails(int id)
    {
        var timeInUser = await _apiService.GetTimeInUserByIdAsync(id);
        return View(timeInUser);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateUserDetails(TimeInUser updatedUser)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var existingUser = await _apiService.GetTimeInUserByIdAsync(updatedUser.Id);

            if (existingUser != null)
            { 
                var updated = await _apiService.UpdateTimeInUserAsync(updatedUser);

                if (updated != null)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Success");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Failed to update the user details.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "User ID not found.");
            }
        }

        return View(updatedUser);
    }
}
```

In the view, I pass the retrieved data to be displayed and use it for update operations, but this did not work when trying to update the data.

```
@model Test.Models.TimeInUser

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h1>Edit Details</h1>

<form asp-action="UpdateUserDetails" method="post">
    <input asp-for="Id" hidden />

    <label asp-for="Name"></label>
    <input asp-for="Name" />

    <label asp-for="Contact"></label>
    <input asp-for="Contact" />

    <label asp-for="TimeIn"></label>
    <input asp-for="TimeIn" />

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Does anyone here know how to solve this issue? I tried so many times but still get nothing to work for update operations.

Comment: I suggest you could set the breakpoint at the [HttpPost] UpdateUserDetails method to see what's the api returned. If it return the error, please post the details error message and how you build that api.